# Passing sessionstorage item into a link JavaScript or HTML

Tags: javascript, html, url, single-sign-on, session-storage

I am trying to create a single sign in, and far as I can think this would probably be the best.

My backend receives the request, checks for email, creates a JWToken and adds it to a link sent per email to the user.

Something along this line

```js
function loadWindow() {
  var setsession = window.sessionStorage.setItem("JWT", 'tokentoken');
  window.open('http://localhost:8080/html/reset-password.html')
}
```

there must be some way, but no matter how I do this, the page will not load with a sessionstorage set.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have actually fixed it!
It needed a const definition..

Just sticking it onto the end did not work, but this seems to:

```js
function loadWindow() {
  const myWindow = window.open('http://localhost:8080/html/reset-password.html');
  myWindow.localStorage.setItem('JWT', 'cat');
}
```

[image]

Of course ideally would be directly sessionStorage, but that is not an option it seems.
I will probably have to write a script that removes it from local and rewrites it to sessionstorage. Not sure if all this is best practice security wise though..

EDIT:
come to think of it, this only works because I am running it from tab to tab, likely that when just opening a link from an email this won't work.

EDIT2:
I also appreached this differently,
By passing the token to the url.com/?token=randomtokennumbersletters

And then creating a js function loadFunction that runs upon loading the page

```
function loadFunction() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('JWT') === null) {
    let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
    let token = params.get("token");
    sessionStorage.setItem('JWT', token) // slaat de token van de link op in localstorage
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).